# Is it possible to disable view-lossage?

Tags: emacs

I use `M-x term` as my primary shell in emacs. However, unlike `M-x shell`,  `view-lossage` will still store my keystroke if my password is prompted. After some search, it looks like there is no way to stop `view-lossage` recording when prompted.

I would like to know, is it possible to disable it completely ? How can I workaround this problem ?

Comment: Hm. I wonder if this isn't an Emacs bug (misfeature). You might try `M-x report-emacs-bug`, to suggest that keys for password input not be remembered for things like `view-lossage`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figure out a way to workaround the problem, using the `clear-this-command-keys` function mentioned in @Sean's comment.

Basic idea is to "clear recorded keys when key is send" by advising `term-send-raw`, I call `clear-this-command-keys` whenever enter is pressed.

```
(defadvice term-send-raw (after clear-recorded-key activate)
  (if (string= (kbd "RET") (this-command-keys))
      (clear-this-command-keys)))
```

Comment: I will accept my answer as long as there is no better way to deal with this problem, because I'm expecting workaround that can be used  in emacs, not change the source code.

Answer (score 5):

`recent-keys` is a C function, so it looks like you'll need to re-compile Emacs.

`keyboard.c`:

```
#define NUM_RECENT_KEYS (300)
```

Just change 300 to 0 and you're done.

Comment: It would be useful to figure out how `M-x shell` prevents password keystrokes from being recorded.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't prevent them from being recorded, but it partially clears the record with `clear-this-command-keys`.